# for loop doesn't iterate through an empty list (find permutations with recursion)

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, permutation, continue

I am trying to generate all the permutations of a given **set** through recursion. Idea is that function will iterate through all the elements of the provided **set**, append each element to a **local output** list while simultaneously modifying the **set** by removing that element as long as **set** is not empty. Once **set** becomes empty, function appends **local output** list to a **master list** and then go back to the execution context to iterate through remaining elements. This approach is summarized in figure below -

[Recursion tree image from YouTube channel 'Time Complexity Infinity'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmPfH.png)

I have written following code in python-

```
master_output = []
output = []
def PermTree(set):
    for element in set:
        if bool(set) is False:
            master_output.append(output)
        else:
            output.append(element)
            set.remove(element)
            PermTree(set)
        output.pop()
    return master_output
result = PermTree([1, 2, 3])
print(result)
```

This function can go through first few iterations but when the **set** becomes empty, it quits. For e.g. in a given **set** of `[1, 2, 3]`, it will go as follows -

```
PermTree([1, 2, 3])
# set not empty > append element to output
output = [1]
# remove element from set
set = [2, 3]
# recursive call to PermTree()
PermTree([2, 3])
# set not empty > append element to output
output = [1, 2]
# remove element from set
set = [3]
# recursive call to PermTree()
PermTree([3])
# set not empty > append element to output
output = [1, 2, 3]
# remove element from set
set = []
# recursive call to PermTree()
PermTree([])
```

This function quits here as **set** has become empty (`if` block doesn't execute). What I would like is that function doesn't quit here and instead append **output** to **master output** and then `pop()` the **output** and then go to the next iteration. That is -

```
PermTree([])
# set empty > append output to master output
# pop() the output
output = [1, 2]
# go to next iteration
PermTree([3])
# element has already been iterated
# pop() the output
output = [1]
# go to next iteration
PermTree([2, 3])
# set not empty > append element ('3') to output ('2' was covered in first iteration)
output = [1, 3]
# remove element from set
set = [2]
# ... and so on..
```

Any suggestion on how to get my code working would be appreciated .I am new to python, so any other syntax improvement suggestions will also be helpful.

Comment: You need `return` before the recursive call: `return PermTree(set)`

Comment: BTW, don't use `set` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in function.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your comments, but adding return before recursive call didn't solve my problem. Function still quits when it sees an empty set as input.

Comment: Isn't an empty set the base case of the recursion? What should it do if there's nothing to iterate over?

Comment: You should put `if bool(set) is False:` outside the loop.

Comment: And it's more pythonic to write `if len(set) == 0:` or `if not set:`

Comment: Using `if bool(set) is False:` outside the loop still doesn't work. When I used input set as [1,2,3] as input set it gave me a traceback instead of the desired **master output** list - [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1].

Comment: Another problem here: You are modifying a collection _while at the same time iterating over it_. That's generally a recipe for disaster. Or at the very least a recipe for wrong outcomes.